# Bootstrap collapse target child element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to use the Bootstrap collapse function, but it should collapse only the next submenu ".menu-lvl2". Using IDs is not possible, the menu is generated code.

This is the current code, but on click it opens and closes both submenus. So the href needs a child selector. I tried already:

- `.menu-lvl2:first-element`: JS Error, first-element is not supported
- `.menu-lvl2:first`: selects always first item on page
- `>.menu-lvl2`, `this>.menu-lvl2`: nothing selected at all

It should be something like: `this>.menu-lvl2`

```
<li>
    <a href=".menu-lvl2" data-toggle="collapse">Menu Element 1</a>
       <ul class="collapse menu-lvl2">
           <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
       </ul>
</li>
<li>
   <a href=".menu-lvl2" data-toggle="collapse">Menu Element 2</a>
      <ul class="collapse menu-lvl2">
          <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Why not possible if the menu is generated code? You can use `.on()` JQuery function which will bind event to current+future elements.

Comment: .menu-lvl2:first-element - you can use `nth-child()` or simply `first-child()`